# Getting Python under control on Mac OS X - setting up environment and libraries

Tags: python, macos, development-environment

After starting out with Python on Ubuntu Linux, I've now for a good while been doing most of my sustained work on the Mac, currently Mac OS X 10.6. Unfortunately I've neglected to give proper attention to how Python is installed there and ended up with:

- Python 2.6.1 (Mac default version?) in `/usr/bin` (also, 2.5.4, which I'm not sure how it got there)
- Python 2.6.5 installed via [MacPorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacPorts) in `/opt/local/bin/`. This is my default
- I use `pip` to install libraries, which end up in some ungodly place (something like `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` - SRSLY?)
- Otherwise, mostly TextMate, and Git for version control. Django and Google App Engine, etc...

Now I'm preparing to set up 2.7 and 3.2, and I am unhappy with the haphazard state of things. So what are your favourite approaches to organising the code and libraries, and how have you wrestled the Mac into submission?

I'd like to continue using `pip`, but would like to have more control or at least understanding of what libraries for which version are getting installed and made accessible from where: I've had problems with installing `py.test` via `pip` and only being able to load it from the obsolete 2.6.1 Python, not my current 2.6.5 one. MacPorts has `python_select`, but it's not overly helpful:

```
reason: chris$ python_select -l
Available versions:
current none python26 python26-apple
```

Most Python people I've asked don't use MacPorts, which I don't much like, but the stock Mac Python from `python.org`. I've also heard the recommendation to use `virtualenv` systematically, so what is the link to a good practical introduction?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`virutalenv` is a great tool and is very useful for managing multiple Python instances on most platforms.  On Mac OS X, though, things are more complicated because the use of framework builds makes it common to encounter multiple instances of even the same major version of Python. I suggest you first understand and be comfortable with how to manage framework installs on Mac OS X before delving into `virtualenv`.

*"`/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/` - SRSLY?"*

Yes, that's the default location within a Python Mac OS X framework build. Most distributors of Python on Mac OS X use a *framework build*, each generally using a different root, because it makes it simpler to support multiple versions and to keep all the site packages installed for a particular Python instance together in one place.

For Mac OS X 10.6, Apple supplies a Python 2.6 (rooted at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` and symlinked to `/usr/bin/python2.6`) as well as a Python 2.5 (for compatibility with Mac OS X 10.5 - that's the `/usr/bin/python2.5` you see). The python.org Mac OS X installers install to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.  MacPorts uses `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

The frameworks include a `bin` directory (at `../Versions/x.x/bin` in the framework); this is normally the default location where package scripts will be installed.  It's also where symlinks to the interpreter binaries are placed.

Here's a look at a python.org-style framework with multiple versions of Python installed:

```
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
$ ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  admin  340 Dec 23  2008 2.5/
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  admin  340 Aug 10 21:42 2.6/
drwxrwxr-x  8 root  admin  340 Jul  3 12:24 2.7/
drwxrwxr-x  7 root  admin  306 Mar 23 17:42 3.1/
drwxrwxr-x  7 root  admin  306 Aug 10 22:14 3.2/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    3 Aug 10 21:47 Current@ -> 2.6
$ cd 2.6
$ ls -l
total 7776
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin       17 Aug 10 21:47 Headers@ -> include/python2.6
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin      102 Aug 10 21:42 Mac/
-r-xrwxr-x  1 root  admin  3973552 Aug 10 21:41 Python*
drwxrwxr-x  4 root  admin      170 Aug 10 21:48 Resources/
drwxrwxr-x  2 root  admin      578 Aug 12 15:19 bin/
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin      102 Aug 10 21:42 include/
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin      646 Aug 10 21:43 lib/
drwxrwxr-x  3 root  admin      102 Aug 10 21:41 share/
$ ls -l bin
total 264
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    150 Aug 10 21:41 2to3*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nad   admin    360 Aug 12 15:19 easy_install*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nad   admin    368 Aug 12 15:19 easy_install-2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin      7 Aug 10 21:47 idle@ -> idle2.6
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    138 Aug 10 21:41 idle2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin      8 Aug 10 21:47 pydoc@ -> pydoc2.6
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    123 Aug 10 21:41 pydoc2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin      9 Aug 10 21:47 python@ -> python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     16 Aug 10 21:47 python-config@ -> python2.6-config
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  29584 Aug 10 21:43 python2.6*
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin   1463 Aug 10 21:42 python2.6-config*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     10 Aug 10 21:47 pythonw@ -> pythonw2.6
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  29584 Aug 10 21:43 pythonw2.6*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     11 Aug 10 21:47 smtpd.py@ -> smtpd2.6.py
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  18272 Aug 10 21:41 smtpd2.6.py*
```

Here's a MacPorts `bin` including a number of additional site packages:

```
$ cd /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6
$ ls -l bin
total 952
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    160 Jul 15 01:56 2to3*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   1541 Jun  8 19:59 apirst2html.py*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    363 Oct  5  2009 bdist_mpkg*
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    211 Jun  2 12:45 django-admin.py*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    410 Jul 15 17:30 easy_install*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    418 Jul 15 17:30 easy_install-2.6*
[...]
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    368 Jun 24 02:00 pip*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    342 Sep 18  2009 pkginfo*
[...]
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel      9 Jul 15 01:58 python@ -> python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     16 Jul 15 01:58 python-config@ -> python2.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel  24932 Jul 15 01:57 python2.6*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel   1473 Jul 15 01:57 python2.6-config*
[...]
```

If you install 2.7 or 3.1 Pythons using python.org installers or MacPorts, they are all rooted under `/Library/Frameworks` or `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks` and will happily co-exist with other versions. To successfully use framework installs, you need to manage your shell `PATH`. In particular, you should ensure that the framework `bin` directory of the Python(s) you want to use are on your `PATH`. So for MacPorts, something like this in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

or for the python.org installers:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:$PATH
```

In addition, generally you need to install a separate version of your favorite Python package management add-ons (like `pip` or the `easy_install` command from `Distribute` or `setuptools`) for each Python instance you use. Each one is installed into the default script directory (i.e. the framework `bin` directory). MacPorts takes care of that automatically when you install its version of the package (`sudo port install py26-pip` or `sudo port install py31-distribute`). Note that Apple supplies a set of `easy_install` links in `/usr/bin` for its Pythons and they install packages to `/Library/Python`. You need to make sure you use the `easy_install` or `pip` appropriate for your instance of Python. Making sure the instance's framework `bin` directory is first in the `PATH` ensures that.

Note, if you use MacPorts you *can* use its `python_select` command to manage which Python instance is pointed to by `/opt/local/bin/python`.  Then if `/opt/local/bin` appears earlier in your PATH list than other directories with a `python` it will govern which is your default `python`.  But you really need to manage the PATH by adding the framework `bin` directory so `python_select` is generally not all that useful.

Another positive aspect of using MacPorts (or similar broad-based distributor) is that it makes available many popular Python packages *including* handling the occasional messy details of building and linking to 3rd-party C libraries not shipped with Mac OS X. For example, the `MySQLdb` and `PIL` packages are frequent stumbling blocks on Mac OS X because of the MySQL client libraries and `libjpeg`, but MacPorts makes it much easier to get everything right. But you do have the choice to install things directly using MacPorts (`sudo port py26-pil`) or via `pip` (`sudo pip install pil`) or `easy_install`, or you can download the source, and do it yourself (`sudo python setup.py ...`).  And because all of them under the covers use Python's `Distutils` to do the dirty work, all of these methods will generally end up installing a package's files in the same place for a given Python instance.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. I have the following sub question. You say: "You need to make sure you use the easy_install or pip appropriate for your instance of Python. Making sure the instance's framework bin directory is first in the PATH ensures that." We're talking here about the same pip and same easy_install just the Python needs to be switched by adding appropriate bins to the beginning of the path. We're not talking about installing some other pip or easy_install, right? Although there are setuptools for different versions. At least this is how I read your two sentences

Comment: You need to install separate copies of `easy_install` for each Python instance; they can be the same version of `easy_install` (particularly if you use the most recent release of Distribute which can be installed with all current versions of Python).  It is easier to do the same thing with `pip`, that is install a copy of `pip` for each Python instance; like `easy_install`, the command will normally be installed in the corresponding `bin` directory of the Python used.  However, `pip` does have an option to specify which Python it should use so you *could* use one:  `pip -E /path/to/python`

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I have struggled in the past with upgrading Python and virtual environments.  I have figured out how to get this to work for the stuff I do.  Hopefully this will help someone.

Setup:
Mac running 10.14
Python 3.7
Various packages: Pandas, IPython, Paramiko, etc.

**Python:**
Just use the installer they provide at [Python.org](https://www.python.org/).  Click on the "Download" button for macOS, download the packages and click through the installer.  Done.  When it comes time to upgrade to the next Python 3 version, repeat the process.
To get the Python3 interpreter on the command-line instead of the Python2 one, use `python3` instead of `python`.

**Getting Rid of Older Python3 versions**
If you don't like the idea of having old Python versions hanging around, open the Applications folder and drag-and-drop the old Python3 version you don't want to the trash.    DO NOT do this to the Python2 versions unless you know what you a re doing.  Some of these came with the OS and will likely cause trouble if they disappear.

**Installing Packages:**.
@Ned Deily's suggestion to use virtual environments is a good one if you want to make installing packages easier.  The virtual environment tool for Python2 is 'virtualenv'.  That tool is called 'venv' in Python3.

**Step 1:**
Create a directory to hold all of your virtual environments.  This isn't necessary, but this is how I keep track of mine.  I keep two separate dirs named 'virtenvs' and 'venvs' depending on whether I'm installing a package for Python2 or Python3.  For this example, we'll use Python3:

`cd ~`
`mkdir venvs`
`cd venvs`

Now, I name my packages after my project or after the major package I've installed.  For this example, let's just call it 'project1':
`venv project1`

**Step 2:**
"Activate" the virtual environment using the following command.  You'll need to to this every time you start a new terminal or session.
`source ~/venvs/project1/bin/activate`

Pip changes a lot, so update it
`pip install --upgrade pip`

**Step 3:**
Now you're ready to start installing packages into your new virtual environment:
`pip install pandas`
etc.

When you're done or you want to switch to a different virtual environment, just type:
`deactivate`

**What's Next:**
Explore the web for more info on Python virtual environments.   Using this approach, I've not run into a package that required MacPorts, Anaconda, etc.  There are undoubtedly packages that do.  YMMV.  Hopefully this approach will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I just used 'pythonbrew', which I easy_installed with the stock system Python on 10.6.7. I had to use the '--force' option to bypass the post-compile tests though, as I had failures with test_dl and test_readline (a quick google check did not show these to be a real issue).

```
$ sudo easy_install pythonbrew
```

Once installed, run this for more instructions:

```
$ pythonbrew_install
```

So I now have a nicely isolated python-2.7.1 installation without interfering with the system installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Homebrew, as do the Python Guide people:

Here is a fantastic step by step guide to getting started:

http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/#install-osx