# How to install/organize python modules on a mac?

Tags: python, installation

I have a mbp, but I've been lazy and have been using ubuntu for my python development thus far b/c its so easy to install modules etc.

How do you install modules on a mac?  And best-practises with storing all .py files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my lengthy answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487664/getting-python-under-control-on-os-x-setting-up-environment-and-libraries/).  Bottom line, if you are familiar and comfortable with a package-managed environment like on Ubuntu, you may want to use a package manager like [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) or [Homebrew](http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) on OS X.  But there are subtle differences since, unlike Ubuntu, this is not the system-wide package manager so you have to be aware of and co-exist with things supplied by Apple in OS X or by having multiple Python installations.

Answer (score 0):

One of the perks of using high level languages is that they function mostly the same on each platform they support. Python is no diffent. You install modules the same way you do on Linux: using easy_install or pip, check them out http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: Better yet, use [Distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute), which is a complete replacement for Setuptools (and uses the same `easy_install` commands) and is the only one which will be supported going forward.