# Could not run jupyter on Mac OS (gives pysqlite2 errror)

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have installed anaconda in mac os sierra. Simple python scripts run fine. However, when I try to run jupyter-notebook it fails.

The error message is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: /Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
 in /Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-darwin.so

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/Users/poudel/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I checked the dylib file, but it is there. What's wrong here?

```
Bhishan:ls /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib*
```

Similar problems:

[No module named _sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3)

But they did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely due to several python envirionments. 
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487664/getting-python-under-control-on-mac-os-x-setting-up-environment-and-libraries).
Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770906/importerror-no-module-named-pysqlite2) maybe relevant.

Also try to see all installed packages with [conda](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-list.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.

For me installing `sqlite` via `brew` solved the issue.

```
brew install sqlite
```